# How to cut the image Rectangular 600x200?

Tags: image, android-studio, android-camera, graphic

how can I fix the size of the cut-rectangle like what I want ?
i would like to get it rectangular 600x200
the user can resize it but proportional only

i use codes like this :

```
private void performCrop() {
Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
cropIntent.setDataAndType(pickedImage, "image/*");
//set crop properties
cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
//indicate aspect of desired crop
cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
//indicate output X and Y
cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 600);
cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
//retrieve data on return
cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
//start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);}
```

[I do not like square form like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEM9L.png)

[I like like this :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luStA.png)

any Idea ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10453446/cropping-pictures-in-android-by-keeping-aspect-ratio

Comment: thanks, it work with : aspectX", 3); and aspectY", 2);  means 3to1  = 600 to 200. :)